# Get decimal value from string using Mule Expression Language and Regex

Tags: regex, mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

This issue involves Mule's MEL and regex. I have the following JSON payload.

```
    {
       "balance": "{Amount={BasicAmount=604.45, MinimumAmount=60 445, CurrencyCode=USD}}"
    }
```

I am able to access the string represented by balance

```
    {Amount={BasicAmount=604.45, MinimumAmount=60 445, CurrencyCode=USD}}
```

I need to access the floating point number 604.45 as a string and apply it as a flow variable. I have therefore implemented the following code in my mule application.

```
    <set-variable variableName="balanceUnrefined" value="#[json:balance]" doc:name="balanceUnrefined"/>
    <logger message="#[flowVars.balanceUnrefined]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-variable variableName="balanceRefined" value="#[regex('\\d+\\.\\d+'.toString(), flowVars.balanceUnrefined)]" doc:name="balanceRefined"/>
    <logger message="#[flowVars.balanceRefined]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

The result of the last logger indicates a null. What am I not doing right? Is it the regex?

Comment: So you need a regex like that? `^{Amount={BasicAmount=(([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,2}))(.*)$` You can access your number accessing group #1 of the regex

Comment: You can have fun here: https://regex101.com try putting my regex on the regex field and below your string ;)

Comment: As your regex seems okay, I delete my answer.

Comment: So, I sleep, then I get a free trial at mulesoft.com an using the Online Designer I tested that your regex is okay. I've also seen that the latest data wave specification is the 2.0 and not the 1.0 (the one you use). I used `scan` function: here an extract of my mule-config.xml: `<ee:set-variable variableName="balance">
<![CDATA[
%dw 2.0 output application/json --- scan(vars.regexpVar, /\d+\.\d+/)[0]
]]>
</ee:set-variable>
</ee:variables>
</ee:transform>
<logger doc:id="b458c5f0-5360-40f4-b68c-b5cf1e48da51" doc:name="Logger" doc:timestamp="1518874066833" message="#[vars.balance]"/>`

Comment: Let me know if you care to have some feedback or do you prefer to wait a user that user the desktop version of Anypoint studio with the old data wave specification 1.0

Comment: Try to use the scan function too. It returns a List<String> so you have to take the first. If it works, if you like, I'll post the answer. Happy to learn always something new XD. Here my logs: http://www.versionestabile.it/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Screen-Shot-2018-02-17-at-3.33.36-PM.png

Comment: Hi @shadowsheep many thanks for your answer and for indeed taking time to really ensure that the issue is closed. I think it would work with dw 1.0 as well. Let me implement and will advise.

Comment: you are welcome. Let me know, and if you like I can post the answer for you!

Comment: @shadowsheep finally solved using the scan function in dataweave 1.0. It looks like: <set-variable variableName="balanceUnrefined" value="#[json:balance]" doc:name="balanceUnrefined"/><set-payload value="#[flowVars.balanceUnrefined]" doc:name="Set Payload"/><dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
 "output": payload scan /\d+\.\d+/
}
]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

Comment: please consider to accept my question for the effort I do to help you. It’s so unfair you have post by your own the answer upon my findings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following our discussion:

Use the `scan` function too. It returns a `List<String>` so you have to take the first. It works well with your regex on dw 2.0 so should do in de 1.0.

That my Mule 4 `mule-config.xml`:

```
<ee:set-variable variableName="balance"> <![CDATA[ %dw 2.0 output application/json --- scan(vars.regexpVar, /\d+\.\d+/)[0] ]]> </ee:set-variable> </ee:variables> </ee:transform> <logger doc:id="b458c5f0-5360-40f4-b68c-b5cf1e48da51" doc:name="Logger" doc:timestamp="1518874066833" message="#[vars.balance]"/>
```

And here my result logs:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @shadowsheep however this wouldn't work since the value of the floating point number can change. I further have tested it and this is the error received in anypoint studio:   Execution of the expression "regex('^{Amount={BasicAmount=(([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,2}))(.*)$'.toString(), flowVars.balanceUnrefined)" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).

Comment: @mdennism Oh, you're right: this one right? `^{Amount={BasicAmount=(([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+))(.*)$`

Comment: @mdennism could it be that the floating point part is also missing? I mean you can get Amount=63 or always Amount=63.0 or 63.00?

Comment: Floating point will always be there either as 78.00 or 3472.38. Your regex on regex101.com captures everything. This works \d+\.\d+ on regex101.com however in Anypoint studio it is not working.

Comment: @mdennism Yep I know that my regex capture your entire string, but what is most important Is that the group #1 is your number. I'm not used with mulesoft any point studio, but with a valid regular expression with your value in a group you could extract the right value from that group.

Comment: @mdennism your expression is not working if you pass the entire string. What I would like to teach you is that a regular expression must match the entire string you pass and than group part of it so that you can extract it from the groups function every language regex API expose to the programmer.

Comment: You can see what the regex does in this image here https://www.dropbox.com/s/639nfc056b7sdqr/Screen%20Shot%202018-02-16%20at%2022.43.09.png?dl=0

Comment: @mdennism yes, you're right. So why it doesn't work? Are you sure you have to escape the '\' char?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use a transformer to use the scan function as recommended by @shadowsheep and credit to him getting this right. This applies to Mule 3.9 and using dataweave 1.0

```html
<set-variable variableName="balanceUnrefined" value="#[json:balance]" doc:name="balanceUnrefined"/>
        <set-payload value="#[flowVars.balanceUnrefined]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
 "balance": payload scan /\d+\.\d+/
}
]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Comment: Please consider to accept my answer 'cause was the right one, and you get the work done thanks to my findings.

Comment: Hi @shadowsheep I have accepted your answer. I only posted my answer for benefit of mule 3.9 and dw1.0 applications. You can see the scan function application is different in both. You could as well post it and I will delete this answer.

Comment: Okay @mdennism now it’s fair ;). Happy to halp and happy coding!

Comment: I have upvoted but i have little reputation so it has only been recorded.

Comment: Okay @mdennism I’ve upvoted you ti help you grow! C’ya!

Comment: Great interaction. Thanks @shadowsheep.